# Cartesian product of two lists into a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x

I have two lists, one containing names, and one numbers. I would like to create the Cartesian product of these lists into a dataframe.
For example list of names is:

```
names_list=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
```

List of numbers:

```
num_list=list(range(1,21))
```

The resulting df would be something like this:

Name    Number

A   1

A   2

A   3

…   …

B   1

B   2

B   3

…   …

Is it possible to create this dataframe without for cycles? Thanks in advance!

Comment: list comprehension is short and straightforward here, why not use it?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: That means that list comprehension which implies `for` looping would be the most straightforward, explicit, and presumably faster way. Besides, post your efforts, show what you have tried.